# Changes in the headers when I read files in R?

Tags: r

Whenever I read in a file using `read.csv()` with option `header=T`, the headers change in weird (but predictable) ways. A header name which ought to read `"P(A<B)"` becomes `"P.A.B."`, for instance:

```
> # when header=F:
> myfile1 <- read.csv(fullpath,sep="\t",header=F,nrow=3)
> myfile1
     V1    V2     V3
1    ID  Name P(A>B)
2 AB001 Alice  0.997
3 AB002   Bob  0.497
>
> # When header=T:
> myfile2 <- read.csv(fullpath,sep="\t",header=T,nrow=3)
> myfile2
     ID    Name P.A.B.
1 AB001   Alice  0.997
2 AB002     Bob  0.497
3 AB003 Charles  0.732
```

I tried to fix it like this, but it didn't work:

```
> names(myfile2) <- myfile1[1,]
> myfile2
      3       3     3
1 AB001   Alice 0.997
2 AB002     Bob 0.497
3 AB003 Charles 0.732
```

So then I tried to use `sub()` to write a function that would take any vector `"arbitrary.lengths.here."` and return a vector `"arbitrary(lengths>here)"`, but I didn't really get anywhere, and I started to suspect that I was making this problem more complicated than it had to be.

How would you deal with this problem of headers? Was I on the right track with `sub()`?

Comment: `read.csv` and its parent function `read.table` have an argument `check.names` which defaults to `TRUE`.  This changes names with odd characters or that start with a number to a more acceptable naming convention.  Try reading your file with `check.names=FALSE`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set `check.names=FALSE` in `read.csv()`

```
read.csv(fullpath,sep="\t", header=FALSE, nrow=3, check.names=FALSE)
```

From the help for `?read.csv`:

*check.names*

*logical. If TRUE then the names of the variables in the data frame are checked to ensure that they are syntactically valid variable names. If necessary they are adjusted (by make.names) so that they are, and also to ensure that there are no duplicates.*

Answer (score 2):

Not really intended as an answer, but intended to be helpful to Rnewbs: Those headers were read in as factors (and caused the third column to also be a factor. The screwy `names()` assignments probably used their integer storage mode. @Andrie has already given you the preferred solution, but if you wanted to just reassign the names (which would not undo the damage to the thrid column) you could use:

```
 names(myfile1) <- scan(file=fullpath, what="character" nmax=1 , sep="\t")
 myfile1 <- myfile[-1, ]    # gets rid of unneeded line
```