# read.table() changes column names

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changes in the headers when I read files in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365424/changes-in-the-headers-when-i-read-files-in-r)

I've encountered weird behavior - I have a table with column names `P(A|AA)`, `P(A|AC)`,....
When I write the table using write.table(), and then read it using read.table(), the column names 
change to `P.A.AA.`, `P.A.AA.` - It seems the read.table does not support column names with special characters.  (The write table works OK, as can be seen in the file, and also the column names before the `write.table()` are OK, so this must be a problem with read.table).

Has anyone else encountered this and knows of a workaround?

Comment: Lots of people have encountered this problem and solved it by reading `?read.table`, specifically the `check.names` argument...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365424/changes-in-the-headers-when-i-read-files-in-r